# Can I have a cache expiration on a single field, and that expiration is respected by storage loading?

Tags: 8, caching

Trying to figure out the best way to go about this.  I have one field added to the `User` entity and I need somewhat fresh data on it.

Ideally I'd be able to cache this one field for, say, 15 minutes.  If `entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(3)` is called after expiration, I need to hit an API and update that data.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Where how do you need that data? Not sure if a field is the best approach, I'd go for a custom API and load the data where you need it

Comment: I'm not sure it is either :).  The data is needed in several places - it's used on custom landing pages to conditionally hide some options, it's used in controllers to conditionally redirect, it's used in Commerce Condition plugins for evaluating promotion/coupons conditions - there may be others.

Comment: I already have a service with `getAccountRemoteSubscriptionsBySub` (which is what hook_user_login uses), I guess instead of trying to save it somewhere I can call that as needed - was trying to save some calls though.

Comment: I think that creates more trouble than it's worth. I'd just stick to calling your service, add some caching there that you control and make sure to add max-age to all things that might being cached, redirect responses and so on.